# Websphere liberty server JCA (Java connector architecture), JNDI and resource adapter

Tags: web-services, jndi, websphere-liberty, jca, resource-adapter

I have created two projects on Eclipse JEE:

1) Connector-ra.rar : this project has java class  and ra.xml. 
This is my resource adapter **ra.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE connector PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Connector 1.0//EN' 'http://java.sun.org/j2ee/dtds/connector_1_0.dtd'>
<connector>
    <display-name>Connector-jca-1</display-name>
    <vendor-name>Volkswagen AG</vendor-name>
    <spec-version>1.0</spec-version>
    <eis-type>Prop</eis-type>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <resourceadapter>
        <managedconnectionfactory-class>com.eis.hw.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl</managedconnectionfactory-class>
        <connectionfactory-interface>com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactory</connectionfactory-interface>
        <connectionfactory-impl-class>com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactoryImpl</connectionfactory-impl-class>
        <connection-interface>com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnection</connection-interface>
        <connection-impl-class>com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionImpl</connection-impl-class>
        <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
        <config-property>
            <config-property-name>HostURL</config-property-name>
            <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
            <config-property-value>127.0.0.1</config-property-value>
        </config-property>
        <authentication-mechanism>
            <authentication-mechanism-type>BasicPassword</authentication-mechanism-type>
            <credential-interface>javax.resource.security.PasswordCredential</credential-interface>
        </authentication-mechanism>
        <reauthentication-support>false</reauthentication-support>
    </resourceadapter>
</connector>
```

2) On my Web project i try to call:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.resource.ResourceException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnection;
import com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactory;


@WebServlet("/JCAServlet")
public class TestRA extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Resource(lookup="eis/ECI")
    private HelloWorldConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

     public TestRA() {
            super();

        }
        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
              String result = " ";



          HelloWorldConnection connection = null;
            try {
                 connection = connectionFactory.getConnection();               
                 result = connection.helloWorldCall();

            } catch (ResourceException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println(result + "Application test");

            out.flush();
          //  connection.close();
        }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

I am configuring a JCA and resource adapter on liberty server.
 here is my **server.xml** on liberty server :

```
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
         <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
        <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
        <feature>jca-1.7</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
        <!--<feature>ejbRemote-3.2</feature>-->
    </featureManager>

       <!--The location of the cicseci.rar needs to be updated to the full path-->
   <resourceAdapter autoStart="true" id="eciResourceAdapter" location="C:/Users/Connector-ra.rar"/>

   <connectionFactory id="eciTest" jndiName="eis/ECI">
      <!--The properties need to be updated to the location of the CICS Transaction Gateway-->
      <properties.eciResourceAdapter connectionUrl="tcp://localhost" portNumber="2006"/>
   </connectionFactory>



    <webApplication id="Connector-web" location="Connector-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" name="Connector-web">
   <classloader classProviderRef="eciResourceAdapter"/>
    </webApplication>

    </server>
```

My problem is              :

```
[ERROR ] SRVE0319E: For the [com.sample.TestRA] servlet, com.sample.TestRA servlet class was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred. CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the java:comp/env/com.sample.TestRA/connectionFactory reference. The exception message was: CWNEN1003E: The server was unable to find the eis/ECI binding with the com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactory type for the java:comp/env/com.sample.TestRA/connectionFactory reference.
```

**messages.log**

```
[08/11/18 14:15:18:991 CET] 00000011 com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage                          I  CWSID0108I: JMS server has started.  
[08/11/18 14:15:19:101 CET] 00000011 com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.AuthConfigFactoryWrapper           I CWWKS1655I: The default Java Authentication SPI for Containers (JASPIC) AuthConfigFactory class com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.ProviderRegistry is being used because the Java security property authconfigprovider.factory is not set. 
[08/11/18 14:15:19:971 CET] 0000002e om.ibm.ws.app.manager.rar.internal.RARApplicationHandlerImpl I J2CA7018I: Installing resource adapter eciResourceAdapter.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:570 CET] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: The Liberty Explore Tool.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:572 CET] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module The Liberty Explore Tool has been bound to default_host.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:568 CET] 0000001c com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: The Liberty Admin Center.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:575 CET] 0000001c com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module The Liberty Admin Center has been bound to default_host.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:574 CET] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9086/ibm/adminCenter/explore-1.0/
[08/11/18 14:15:21:570 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: ibm/api.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:579 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module ibm/api has been bound to default_host.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:571 CET] 00000032 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: The Liberty Server Config Tool.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:571 CET] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: IBMJMXConnectorREST.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:581 CET] 00000032 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module The Liberty Server Config Tool has been bound to default_host.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:581 CET] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module IBMJMXConnectorREST has been bound to default_host.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:587 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9086/ibm/api/
[08/11/18 14:15:21:588 CET] 0000001c com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9086/adminCenter/
[08/11/18 14:15:21:594 CET] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9086/IBMJMXConnectorREST/
[08/11/18 14:15:21:618 CET] 0000002e org.jboss.weld.Version                                       I WELD-000900: 2.4.5 (Final)
[08/11/18 14:15:21:666 CET] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.server.rest.RESTAppListener         I CWWKX0103I: The JMX REST connector is running and is available at the following service URL: service:jmx:rest://localhost:9543/IBMJMXConnectorREST
[08/11/18 14:15:21:718 CET] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN8501I: The session manager did not find a persistent storage location; HttpSession objects will be stored in the local application server's memory.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:746 CET] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.server.rest.RESTAppListener         I CWWKX0103I: The JMX REST connector is running and is available at the following service URL: service:jmx:rest://localhost:9543/IBMJMXConnectorREST
[08/11/18 14:15:21:747 CET] 00000020 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/ibm/api
[08/11/18 14:15:21:746 CET] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/ibm/adminCenter/explore-1.0
[08/11/18 14:15:21:748 CET] 0000002c com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/adminCenter
[08/11/18 14:15:21:767 CET] 00000032 com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9086/ibm/adminCenter/serverConfig-1.0/
[08/11/18 14:15:21:785 CET] 00000032 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/ibm/adminCenter/serverConfig-1.0
[08/11/18 14:15:21:788 CET] 00000020 com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:820 CET] 00000032 com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:824 CET] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:826 CET] 0000002c com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[08/11/18 14:15:21:851 CET] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/IBMJMXConnectorREST
[08/11/18 14:15:21:852 CET] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[08/11/18 14:15:22:113 CET] 0000002c com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheServiceImpl                            I DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully.
[08/11/18 14:15:22:543 CET] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.server.rest] [/IBMJMXConnectorREST] [JMXRESTProxyServlet]: Initialization successful.
[08/11/18 14:15:22:808 CET] 0000002e om.ibm.ws.app.manager.rar.internal.RARApplicationHandlerImpl A J2CA7001I: Resource adapter eciResourceAdapter installed in 2.837 seconds.
[08/11/18 14:15:22:915 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      I CWWKZ0018I: Starting application informationrequest-ui.
[08/11/18 14:15:22:928 CET] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      I CWWKZ0018I: Starting application SoapApp0.
[08/11/18 14:15:22:937 CET] 0000002e com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      I CWWKZ0018I: Starting application Connector-web.
[08/11/18 14:15:23:311 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: informationrequest-ui.
[08/11/18 14:15:23:312 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module informationrequest-ui has been bound to default_host.
[08/11/18 14:15:23:314 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9086/informationrequest-ui/
[08/11/18 14:15:23:315 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0001I: Application informationrequest-ui started in 0.400 seconds.
[08/11/18 14:15:23:342 CET] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/informationrequest-ui
[08/11/18 14:15:23:342 CET] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[08/11/18 14:15:23:690 CET] 0000001c com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.mbeans.PluginGenerator          I SRVE9103I: A configuration file for a web server plugin was automatically generated for this server at C:\Users\abdelkarim.chokri\Desktop\ELSA\Tools\wlp-webProfile7-17.0.0.4\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\logs\state\plugin-cfg.xml.
[08/11/18 14:15:24:418 CET] 00000020 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.mbeans.PluginGenerator          I SRVE9103I: A configuration file for a web server plugin was automatically generated for this server at C:\Users\abdelkarim.chokri\Desktop\ELSA\Tools\wlp-webProfile7-17.0.0.4\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\logs\state\plugin-cfg.xml.
[08/11/18 14:15:28:602 CET] 0000002e com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: Connector-web.
[08/11/18 14:15:28:602 CET] 0000002e com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module Connector-web has been bound to default_host.
[08/11/18 14:15:28:603 CET] 0000002e com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9086/Connector-web/
[08/11/18 14:15:28:607 CET] 0000002e com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0001I: Application Connector-web started in 5.668 seconds.
[08/11/18 14:15:28:963 CET] 00000032 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.mbeans.PluginGenerator          I SRVE9103I: A configuration file for a web server plugin was automatically generated for this server at C:\Users\abdelkarim.chokri\Desktop\ELSA\Tools\wlp-webProfile7-17.0.0.4\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\logs\state\plugin-cfg.xml.
[08/11/18 14:15:29:066 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/Connector-web
[08/11/18 14:15:29:067 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[08/11/18 14:15:31:183 CET] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: SoapApp0.
[08/11/18 14:15:31:183 CET] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module SoapApp0 has been bound to default_host.
[08/11/18 14:15:31:183 CET] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9086/SoapApp0/
[08/11/18 14:15:31:187 CET] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0001I: Application SoapApp0 started in 8.259 seconds.
[08/11/18 14:15:31:319 CET] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [servlet-3.1, beanValidation-1.1, ssl-1.0, jndi-1.0, jca-1.7, jms-2.0, ejbPersistentTimer-3.2, appSecurity-2.0, j2eeManagement-1.1, jdbc-4.1, jaxrs-2.0, wasJmsServer-1.0, javaMail-1.5, adminCenter-1.0, cdi-1.2, webProfile-7.0, jpa-2.1, jcaInboundSecurity-1.0, jsp-2.3, ejbLite-3.2, managedBeans-1.0, jsf-2.2, ejbHome-3.2, jaxws-2.2, localConnector-1.0, jsonp-1.0, restConnector-1.0, el-3.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, concurrent-1.0, appClientSupport-1.0, ejbRemote-3.2, javaee-7.0, jaxb-2.2, mdb-3.2, jacc-1.5, batch-1.0, ejb-3.2, json-1.0, jaspic-1.1, jpaContainer-2.1, distributedMap-1.0, websocket-1.1, wasJmsSecurity-1.0, wasJmsClient-2.0].
[08/11/18 14:15:31:319 CET] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 34.273 seconds.
[08/11/18 14:15:31:320 CET] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0011I: The server defaultServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
[08/11/18 14:15:31:470 CET] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/SoapApp0
[08/11/18 14:15:31:471 CET] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[08/11/18 14:15:31:742 CET] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.mbeans.PluginGenerator          I SRVE9103I: A configuration file for a web server plugin was automatically generated for this server at C:\Users\abdelkarim.chokri\Desktop\ELSA\Tools\wlp-webProfile7-17.0.0.4\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\logs\state\plugin-cfg.xml.
[08/11/18 14:15:31:961 CET] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [SoapApp0] [/SoapApp0] [AdminServlet]: Initialization successful.
[08/11/18 14:15:34:040 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.BootstrapContextImpl                 W J2CA8501E: Property portNumber of configuration element eis/ECI cannot be set because it is not found on the class com.eis.hw.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.
[08/11/18 14:15:34:135 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.RecoveryDirectorImpl              I CWRLS0010I: Performing recovery processing for local WebSphere server (defaultServer).
[08/11/18 14:15:37:437 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.RecoveryDirectorImpl              I CWRLS0012I: All persistent services have been directed to perform recovery processing for this WebSphere server (defaultServer).
[08/11/18 14:15:37:438 CET] 00000049 com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager                          I WTRN0135I: Transaction service recovering no transactions.
[08/11/18 14:15:37:620 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactory field com.sample.TestRA.connectionFactory to com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactoryImpl com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionTarget.inject 140" at ffdc_18.11.08_14.15.37.0.log
[08/11/18 14:15:38:379 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: CWNEN0074E: The com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactoryImpl type of the object instance obtained for the java:comp/env/com.sample.TestRA/connectionFactory reference is incompatible with the type of the private com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactory com.sample.TestRA.connectionFactory member. com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet 228" at ffdc_18.11.08_14.15.37.1.log
[08/11/18 14:15:38:380 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              E SRVE0319E: For the [com.sample.TestRA] servlet, com.sample.TestRA servlet class was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred. CWNEN0074E: The com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactoryImpl type of the object instance obtained for the java:comp/env/com.sample.TestRA/connectionFactory reference is incompatible with the type of the private com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactory com.sample.TestRA.connectionFactory member.
[08/11/18 14:15:38:986 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0319E: For the [com.sample.TestRA] servlet, com.sample.TestRA servlet class was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred. CWNEN0074E: The com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactoryImpl type of the object instance obtained for the java:comp/env/com.sample.TestRA/connectionFactory reference is incompatible with the type of the private com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactory com.sample.TestRA.connectionFactory member. com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest() 302" at ffdc_18.11.08_14.15.38.0.log
[08/11/18 14:15:39:081 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0319E: For the [com.sample.TestRA] servlet, com.sample.TestRA servlet class was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred. CWNEN0074E: The com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactoryImpl type of the object instance obtained for the java:comp/env/com.sample.TestRA/connectionFactory reference is incompatible with the type of the private com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactory com.sample.TestRA.connectionFactory member. com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter 144" at ffdc_18.11.08_14.15.38.1.log
[08/11/18 14:15:39:222 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0319E: For the [com.sample.TestRA] servlet, com.sample.TestRA servlet class was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred. CWNEN0074E: The com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactoryImpl type of the object instance obtained for the java:comp/env/com.sample.TestRA/connectionFactory reference is incompatible with the type of the private com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactory com.sample.TestRA.connectionFactory member. com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters 1064" at ffdc_18.11.08_14.15.39.0.log
[08/11/18 14:15:39:222 CET] 0000001f com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               E SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0319E: For the [com.sample.TestRA] servlet, com.sample.TestRA servlet class was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred. CWNEN0074E: The com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactoryImpl type of the object instance obtained for the java:comp/env/com.sample.TestRA/connectionFactory reference is incompatible with the type of the private com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactory com.sample.TestRA.connectionFactory member.
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:5006)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:314)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:995)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:957)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:357)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:499)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:433)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:313)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:284)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:501)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:571)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:926)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1015)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0319E: For the [com.sample.TestRA] servlet, com.sample.TestRA servlet class was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred. CWNEN0074E: The com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactoryImpl type of the object instance obtained for the java:comp/env/com.sample.TestRA/connectionFactory reference is incompatible with the type of the private com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactory com.sample.TestRA.connectionFactory member.
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet(ServletWrapper.java:1503)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:587)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.JaspiServletFilter.doFilter(JaspiServletFilter.java:56)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:995)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1004)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1414)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.JaspiServletFilter.doFilter(JaspiServletFilter.java:56)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:995)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4962)
    ... 19 more
```

Please help me to solve this problem or at least to debug this issue to proceed further. There is no much information in Google as well since I'm trying to use IBM Liberty.

Comment: Change/add logging element to server.xml like this ` <logging consoleLogLevel="INFO"/>` and see if during startup your resource adapter is started correctly and whether connection factory is bound to JNDI. You can edit your question and add message.log output form the server startup

Comment: the resource adapter is started on the server.
 ` [AUDIT   ] J2CA7001I: Resource adapter eciResourceAdapter installed in 3.679 seconds. `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the log I see the following issues:

```
J2CA8501E: Property portNumber of configuration element eis/ECI cannot be set because it is not found on the class com.eis.hw.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.
```

looks like configuration/implementation issue

and

```
CWNEN0074E: The com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactoryImpl type of the object
instance obtained for the java:comp/env/com.sample.TestRA/connectionFactory reference is 
incompatible with the type of the private com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactory 
com.sample.TestRA.connectionFactory member.
```

So you have some classloader issues, make sure you dont have any resource adapter related classes in the application itself, as jar/rar included in WEB-INF/lib or anywhere else.

Comment: I need the jar from resourse adapter because i have this object in my java class TestRA.java  .
` @Resource(lookup="eis/ECI")
    private HelloWorldConnectionFactory connectionFactory;`
I have imported in my java class:
`import com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnection;
import com.eis.hw.HelloWorldConnectionFactory;`

Comment: `import` has nothing to do with bundling jar with your app. This jar should be specified as dependency only for `build or provided`, as in `runtime` it will be provided by the adapter classpath (what you specify in server.xml). So please make sure that your web project (war/ear) doesnt include adapter. Alternatively you can bundle adapter in your ear, but then configure it differently in server.xml see this - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_jca_config_resadapters.html

Comment: thank you very much. it works now.
I have added this tag in the  pom.xml to exclud jar files from the WAR.


 `<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
   <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/Connector-jca-1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</packagingExcludes>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>`

Comment: I'm glad it worked. If you are using maven, it should be enough to mark that dependency to `Connector-jca-1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` as `provided`, in that case it shouldn't be placed in the `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: Thank you very much. I have used the option provided.
`<scope>provided</scope>`
It is the best solution.